# Adobe AIR App install Error #2032

Tags: air

I created an Adobe AIR application using html, css and Javascript. The application works fine, but now that I have built the installer I get the following error:

> Sorry, an error has occurred.
>   The application could not be installed. Try installing it again. If the problem persists, contact the application author.
>
> Error# 2032

I am the application author...

The link to the installer: http://www.bendelcorp.com/tools/default_badge.html

The Flash Vars code:

```
'flashvars','appname=Bendel-Tools&appurl=http://www.bendelcorp.com/tools/Bendel-Tools.air&airversion=1.5&imageurl=icon2.png',
    'movie','badge' );
```

I would appreciate any assistance for resolving this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this app: http://knomedia.com/air/badgeBuilder/ - Badge Builder

Comment: Quick followup. I tried the Badge Builder and I still get the same error. Here is the new link:

http://www.bendelcorp.com/tools/index.html

Comment: have you tried to rebuild app, rename it, build an empty application, use all options in app publishing?

Comment: I have tried these things. I have rebuilt it and it installs properly on my computer, but I continue to get the 2032 error. I am trying another option now. If I sent you the app it would work on your computer.

Answer (score 3):

I too was getting an error `2032` when attempting to install a .AIR file.

After hours of scanning log files, reading blogs and composing a lengthy StackOverflow question, I realized it was because I'd spelt the name of the .AIR file incorrectly.

This demonstrates that code #2032 can be for any number of reasons.

It would be nicer if the logs simply said `File Not Found`.

Answer (score 2):

> After some research, I found that the
>   solution to the problem was to set the
>   .air MIME type for IIS to:
>   application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip

http://brianchau.wordpress.com/2009/11/13/error-2032-with-air-app-installation/

http://blog.joshbuhler.com/2008/06/30/air-installer-badge-error-2032/

Hope this helps,
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to this problem! Steps:

- First navigate to your "C:\Users(User Name)\AppData\Local\" folder.
- Secondly launch the Adobe Download Assistant that you have downloaded.
- Thirdly find the newly created folder that was just created after launching the Adobe Download Assistant. This will be found in the "C:\Users(User Name)\AppData\Local\" and the folder that was just created will be called AIR(some number).tmp.
- Once you have located it you want to navigate to the folder Adobe Download Assistant. So it should look something like this "C:\Users(User Name)\AppData\Local\Temp\AIR3248.tmp\Adobe Download Assistant" This is what it looked like for me, your number will most likely be different.
- Once there you want to open the application file called "Adobe Download Assistant". It will ask you to login with your Adobe profile, if you do not have one just create a new one and then you will be able to bypass this error when attempting to install Adobe AIR or any trial, such as the new Adobe Master Collection CS6.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when installing an .air file from a network drive. Copying it to my local drive solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The info here fixed it for me.

http://userflex.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/io-stream-errors-in-air/

Basically it suggested  adding an extra listener HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, but ignoring the event:

urlStream.addEventListener(air.HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, skip);